# JQuery Expanding Sections

Tags: jquery

I have three sections that are expandable (slideDown) upon click, which is working well. However, I have buttons within the expanded sections that should close the opened sections but only the first section's close button actually closes it's section. The second and third section's close buttons do not close even though all classes and ID's that I am targeting are the same.

HTML

```
<div id="first-section">
<a id="first-section-link"></a>
</div>

<div id="second-section">
<a id="second-section-link"></a>
</div>

<div id="third-section">
<a id="third-section-link"></a>
</div>

<div id="first-expanded" class="expanded-section">
<a id="closeBtn"></a>
</div>

<div id="second-expanded" class="expanded-section">
<a id="closeBtn"></a>
</div>

<div id="third-expanded" class="expanded-section">
<a id="closeBtn"></a>
</div>
```

JQuery

```
$('#closeBtn').on('click', function() {
    $('.expanded-section').slideUp(350);
});

$('#first-section-link').on('click', function() {
    $('#first-expanded').delay(350).slideDown(350);
});

$('#second-section-link').on('click', function() {
    $('#second-expanded').delay(350).slideDown(350);
});

$('#third-section-link').on('click', function() {
    $('#third-expanded').delay(350).slideDown(350);
});
```

Comment: You have invalid HTML. `id`'s value should be unique across whole HTML document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the same `id` attribute on each element. Instead of `id` use `class`:

```
<a class="closeBtn"></a>
```

Comment: Damn, rookie mistake. Thank you for the help, that did the trick.